# Specifying python interpreter from virtualenv in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv

Today I've been trying to bring more of the Python related modes into
my Emacs configuration but I haven't had much luck.

First what I've noticed is that depending on how Emacs is
launched (terminal vs from the desktop), the interpreter it decides to
use is different.

- launched from KDE menu: <kbd>M-! which python</kbd> gives `/usr/bin/python`
- launched from terminal: <kbd>M-! which python</kbd> gives `~/local/bin/python`

I can kind of accept this since I have my *.bashrc* appending
*~/local/bin* to the path and I guess KDE ignores that by default. I can
work around this, however what I don't understand is then if I
activate a virtualenv, I would expect <kbd>M-!</kbd> which python to point to
*~/project.env/bin/python* however it still points to *~/local/bin/python*.

Thus when I <kbd>M-x py-shell</kbd>, I get *~/local/bin/python* so if I try to
<kbd>M-x py-execute-buffer</kbd> on a module that resides in a package in the
virtualenv, *py-shell* will complain about not knowing about modules
also in the virtualenv.

Setting *py-python-command* to "~/project.env/bin/python" seems to have no
effect after everything is loaded.

So I guess the overall crux of my question is, how does one get all
the python related emacs stuff pointing at the right interpreter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems that python-shell does the right thing by picking up the environment settings, whereas py-shell does not. python-shell is provided by python.el and py-shell is provided by python-mode.el , There's bug reports etc related to this, so I'm just not going to use py-shell for now. Figured I'd close the loop on this in case the google machine considers this a high ranking item for one reason or another.

Comment: A useful page on using virtualenv with Emacs (since I found this page via Google): http://jesselegg.com/archives/2010/03/14/emacs-python-programmers-2-virtualenv-ipython-daemon-mode/

Comment: (updated link of the comment above: http://jesselegg.com/archives/emacs-python-programmers-2-virtualenv-ipython-daemon-mode/)

Comment: Mirror : https://web.archive.org/web/20120120144128/http://jesselegg.com:80/archives/2010/03/14/emacs-python-programmers-2-virtualenv-ipython-daemon-mode/

Answer (score 4):

There is a [virtualenv mode for Emacs](https://github.com/aculich/virtualenv.el). It requires Emacs 23.1 or higher.

> This is a minor mode for setting the
>   virtual environment for the Python
>   shell using virtualenv and supports
>   both python-mode.el and python.el.

Comment: But the use of that tool precludes the use of virtualenvwrapper

Comment: Your post refers to [my old virtualenv package](https://github.com/aculich/virtualenv.el) that I no longer maintain; there are at least 3 newer, actively maintained packages: [virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el), [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv), [python-environment](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-python-environment)